# Angular5 handleErrors with Observable : error Observable.throw is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

could you please help me to fix this error ?

**core.js:1542 ERROR TypeError: rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Observable.throw is not a function**

**Angular CLI: 6.0.8 / rxjs 6.2.1**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './../classes/user';
import { AppSettings } from './appSettings';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LoginService {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

      login(user:User): Observable<User> {                               
            return this.http.post<User>(AppSettings.BASE_URL + "/login",user)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleServerError));   
      }

      handleServerError(error: any  | any) {
            console.log(error.error || error.json() || error);
            return Observable.throw(error.error || error.json() || error || 'Server error');  <<< ERROR
      }

}
```

Comment: `Observable.throw` doesn't exist in RxJS 6 and you have to use `import { throwError } from 'rxjs';` instead and you'll use it the same way `throwError(error.error || ...)`. Also see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: I don't think this could work because Import {throwError } from 'rxjs'... it's already in

Answer (score 2):

I've solved like that:

**app.module.ts**

```
 import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
 .
 .
 . 
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
```

**service/login.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './../classes/user';
import { AppSettings } from './appSettings';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import {  throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
      })}


@Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LoginService {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient){

      }

      login(user:User): Observable<User> {                               
            return this.http.post<User>(AppSettings.BASE_URL + "/login",user)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleServerError));   
      }

      handleServerError(error: any | any ) {
            console.log(error.error || error.json() || error);
            return throwError(error.error || error.json() || error || 'Server error');
      }

}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
 import { LoginService } from '../../services/login';

this.loginService.login(new User("admin","admin")).subscribe(                  
                  user => {
                        //to do ; 
                  },
                  error => {                                                  
                         throw error;
                  }                  
  );
```

Comment: login(user:User): Observable<User> {                               
            return this.http.post<User>(AppSettings.BASE_URL + "/login",user)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleServerError));   
} - - doesn't compile